# When the soft keyboard is shown on Activity, but the software keyboard flashes after the popupwindow pops up on the Samsung mobile phone

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, popupwindow

I have a chat activity. At the bottom is `EditText`. On the top is the message displayed by `recyclerView`. Click the message to pop up the pop window.
The situation is like this: When my `EditText` gets the focus and pops up the soft keyboard, click an item in `recyclerView` to pop up the pop window. However, on the Samsung mobile phone, the soft keyboard flashes, just like lifting it up again, but my demand is to keep the soft keyboard popping up but not flashing. Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add inputMethodMode on the popWindow.

```
popupWindow.inputMethodMode = PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NOT_NEEDED
```